# MySQL Query to calculate the Previous Month

Tags: mysql

I would like to calculate total order amount in the previous month.

I got the query for getting the data for the present month from the current date.

```
SELECT SUM(goods_total) AS Total_Amount  FROM orders
WHERE order_placed_date >= date_sub(current_date, INTERVAL 1 MONTH);
```

Now how can I get Previous Months Data only, excluding this month.

For e.g. This month (July) I made $15,000 and last Month(June) i made $14,000.

I get the $15,000 by running the above query.

But i dont know how to calculate Previous Months.

Comment: "WHERE AND" - take out the AND.

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out, i had it in there accidently.

Answer (score 75, accepted):

Here you go, use this to get the date between the 1st of last month and the last of last month in MySQL:

```
... order_placed_date BETWEEN DATE_FORMAT(NOW() - INTERVAL 1 MONTH, '%Y-%m-01 00:00:00')
AND DATE_FORMAT(LAST_DAY(NOW() - INTERVAL 1 MONTH), '%Y-%m-%d 23:59:59')
```

Comment: You're welcome. I had the same problem a few months back and came up with that.

Comment: I am using current_date instead of NOW()

Comment: NOW() is the same as CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, which really here is the same as CURRENT_DATE.

Comment: So theres no difference in using NOW() in place of current_date in terms of performance

Comment: Yeah, all it does is give a reference point in calculating the dates, so it doesn't matter.

Comment: This query will actually leave off the last day of the month, because it is setting the end point of the interval at 00:00:00 of the last day.

Comment: @JL Fixed the query, thanks. I actually noticed the same years ago and fixed it in my local queries, but forgot about this answer.

Answer (score 12):

Simplest solution:

```
SELECT SUM(goods_total) AS Total_Amount FROM orders
WHERE YEAR(order_placed_date) = YEAR(CURDATE() - INTERVAL 1 MONTH)
AND MONTH(order_placed_date) = MONTH(CURDATE() - INTERVAL 1 MONTH)
```

Answer (score 9):

I found that Artem's query wasn't returning anything from the last day of the previous month(presumably as BETWEEN would calculate from time 00:00:00 of the last day).

This seems to work for me for the previous month.

```
order_placed_date BETWEEN DATE_FORMAT(NOW() - INTERVAL 1 MONTH, '%Y-%m-01')
AND DATE_FORMAT(NOW() ,'%Y-%m-01')
```

Comment: I've updated my query to work correctly, slightly differently from yours.

Answer (score 2):

here another solution - without stringoperation

```
SELECT SUM(goods_total) AS Total_Amount  FROM orders
WHERE  DATE(order_placed_date) 
BETWEEN DATE_ADD(LAST_DAY(DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 2 MONTH)), INTERVAL 1 DAY) 
AND LAST_DAY(DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 MONTH));
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is another way i found:

```
SELECT SUM(goods_total) AS Total_Amount  FROM orders
WHERE SUBSTRING(o.order_placed_date FROM 1 FOR 7) =   SUBSTRING(CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 1 MONTH FROM 1 FOR 7)
```

This works as well.

Comment: Same problem as above, I would think. Run all SELECTs through EXPLAIN (just prepend EXPLAIN to each SELECT) and see what kind of information EXPLAIN gives you about the efficiency of each query.

Comment: That is, assuming you created an index on order_placed_date. You did, right? RIGHT?

Comment: Under Indexes, order_placed_date settings are: Non_Unique = 1, Seq_in_Index = 1, IndexType= BTREE

Answer (score 0):

If you are lazy it's kinda convenient to use

`...date_format(order_placed_date, '%Y-%m') = date_format(now() - INTERVAL 1 MONTH, '%Y-%m')`

I think it also increases readability.

Comment: The problem with your query is that it will do a full table scan and will have horrible performance on large data sets because it will not use an index. The query with BETWEEN that I posted uses a range, so it'll be able to utilize an index. The readability... I think both are readable :)

Comment: Oh and FYI, MySQL doesn't support function based indexes. PostgreSQL supposedly does.

Comment: Sorry, I see that now. I'm just used doing that from tables with up to a couple hundred records. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

One more way to do this with:

**DATE_ADD**

```
... WHERE order_placed_date >= DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL -60 DAY) 
      AND order_placed_date <= DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL -30 DAY)
```