# PHP Query for Counting by Date

Tags: php, mysql, count

I have a database table called books

`books ('id', 'sku', 'date_added')`

where `date_added` is DATETIME.

I need to run a query to find all books by count added last month. Now i can do it and get a list but for dates nothing was uploaded, i would need a 0. How do i achieve this?

Also what query would give me a count of books uploaded by month?

Comment: Look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1138190/mysql-query-to-calculate-the-previous-month

Comment: I am not able to get 0's for days nothing has been added. I could not find the solution on that link.

Comment: Look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2157282/generate-days-from-date-range