# SQL querying to find record for last 3 months

Tags: sql, database, categories, querying

Hello I am a newbie when it comes to sql so please bear with me.

So I have two tables one is a `Transaction` table and the other is a `Category` table.

The `Transaction` table consists of transaction information which includes:

```
date, description, amount, category_id
```

This table will hold all transactions.

The `Category` table consists of: `categoryId , name`

Categories for example will be like "Entertainment", "Shopping", "Food", ...etc.)

What I want to do is be able to check for all category types of transactions that have occurred in each of the past 3 months and return these categories.

For example:

If I ran this query today (December) and let's say that there were "Shopping" transactions that took place for the months of September (8/3/2012), October (9/9/2012), and November (10/15/2012) the query should return "Shopping" because in the last 3 months shopping transactions took place.

The query can return multiple categories as long as there were past transactions for a category in each of the past 3 months. I hope I make sense.

Any helpful advice or examples will be appreciated.

Thanks,
Asean

Answer (score 1):

You want to use the function date_sub.

Check out this: [Older Stackoverflow Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1138190/mysql-query-to-calculate-the-previous-month)

And read up on date_sub function: [MySQL Reference](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-sub)

Answer (score 0):

These sql is not tested. Just created it on the fly..

**MSSQL**

```
SELECT Category.name FROM Category INNER JOIN Transaction ON Category.categoryId = Transaction .category_id where DATEDIFF(mm,Transaction.date, Now()) <= 3 GROUP BY Category.name
```

**MYSQL**

```
SELECT DISTINCT Category.name FROM Category INNER JOIN Transaction ON Category.categoryId = Transaction .category_id where PERIOD_DIFF(EXTRACT(YEAR_MONTH FROM NOW()), EXTRACT(YEAR_MONTH FROM Transaction.date)) <= 3
```