# MySQL: Select previous month and month before

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to write a reporting page that will

**(PART A)** Select records from the current calendar month (so if accessed on June 10, it will show records from June 1 to June 10)

**(PART B)** Then another section for the previous calendar month (so May 1 to May 31).

I've played around with the example in this discussion [MySQL Query to calculate the Previous Month](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1138190/mysql-query-to-calculate-the-previous-month)
But am a little bit confused.

Will

```
SELECT Count(*) 
FROM `table` 
WHERE table.timestamp BETWEEN date_format(NOW() - INTERVAL 1 MONTH, '%Y-%m-01') AND last_day(NOW() - INTERVAL 1 MONTH)
```

satisfy **(PART A)** or **(PART B)**? 
It seems like it is **(PART A)** but I am pretty confused.

Can you help me build both queries? This SQL datetime stuff really messes with my head.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you subtract the current day of the month from the date and add 1, you have the beginning of the current month.  You can use this logic:

```
where time between date_sub(curdate(), interval day(curdate()) - 1 day) and
                   date_sub(date_add(date_sub(curdate(), interval day(curdate()) - 1 day), interval 1 month), interval -1 day)
```

Comment: Ahhh, that makes a lot of sense.

Comment: Since `BETWEEN` matches the range inclusive to the endpoints, wouldn't you want to subtract a day from the end? Otherwise, you'll match timestamps on the first day of the subsequent month...