# SELECT UNION: MySQL Select month, previous month - 1, month - 3

Tags: mysql, sql, select, output, union

Edited as per @gordon's comment ---

Supposed the following scenario

```
CREATE TABLE card (date_field, numcard, month);

INSERT INTO card (date_filed, numcard, month) 
VALUES
    (2018-06-01, 12531, June-2018),
    (2018-06-02, 29182, June-2018),
    (2018-05-01, 12781, May-2018),
    (2018-05-29, 56171, May-2018),
    (2018-05-10, 27191, May-2108),
    (2018-04-10, 83231, April-2018),
    (2018-03-01, 31131, March-2018),
    (2018-03-02, 47131, March-2018),
    (2018-02-15, 34617, February-2018);
```

With this scenario, I am trying to have the number of card for June-2018 (M), May-2018 (M-1) and March-2018 (M-3) using one query... AND THE OUTPUT is supposed to be a 1X3 Matrix like this ...[Desired Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FX3xW.png)

I tried to solve it using using the query below:

> in the quest to solve my question, I came across this discussion
>   [MySQL Query to calculate the Previous Month](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1138190/mysql-query-to-calculate-the-previous-month) and this one :
>   [MySQL: Select previous month and month before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31706846/mysql-select-previous-month-and-month-before?rq=1)

```
    SELECT count(*) as 'M', '' as'M-1', '' as 'M-3' FROM my_table WHERE YEAR(date_field) = YEAR(CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 2 MONTH) AND MONTH(date_field) = MONTH(CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 2 MONTH)
UNION
    SELECT '' as 'M', count(*) as'M-1', '' as 'M-3'  FROM my_table WHERE YEAR(date_field) = YEAR(CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 3 MONTH) AND MONTH(date_field) = MONTH(CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 3 MONTH)
UNION
    SELECT '' as 'M', '' as 'M-1', count(*) as 'M-3'  FROM my_table WHERE YEAR(date_field) = YEAR(CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 4 MONTH) AND MONTH(date_field) = MONTH(CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 4 MONTH)
```

... it gives a

[image: 3X3 Matrix]

with value (the bits :-( ...) on the diagonal only.

What I would like to have is this

[image: Desired Output].

*** Thank you for your help and insights.
Happy weekend!

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Hi.. I edited the question. Hope it is better now. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use conditional aggregation. Only count the rows, which satisfy the condition. Do that with a `CASE` that returns any non null value if the condition is met. Otherwise `CASE` will per default return null and as `count(ex)` doesn't count a row if `ex` evaluates to `NULL`, the row isn't counted.

You might also want to rework your conditions in a way, that `date_field` is the complete expression on one side of a comparison operator, so that indexes on `date_field` can be used. (Not that important for the expressions in the `WHEN`s but for those in the `WHERE` clause.)

```
SELECT count(CASE
               WHEN date_field >= current_date - interval 2 month - interval dayofmonth(current_date) - 1 day
                    AND date_field < current_date - interval 1 month - interval dayofmonth(current_date) - 1 day THEN
                 1
             END) `M`,
       count(CASE
               WHEN date_field >= current_date - interval 3 month - interval dayofmonth(current_date) - 1 day
                    AND date_field < current_date - interval 2 month - interval dayofmonth(current_date) - 1 day THEN
                 1
             END) `M-1`,
       count(CASE
               WHEN date_field >= current_date - interval 4 month - interval dayofmonth(current_date) - 1 day
                    AND date_field < current_date - interval 3 month - interval dayofmonth(current_date) - 1 day THEN
                 1
             END) `M-3`,
       FROM my_table
       WHERE date_field >= current_date - interval 4 month - interval dayofmonth(current_date) - 1 day
             AND date_field < current_date - interval 1 month - interval dayofmonth(current_date) - 1 day;
```

Answer (score 0):

There's almost certainly a better way to do what you're looking to do but given what you have there, you could do something like this:

```
select max(a), max(b), max(c) from(
  select '1' as a, ''as b, '' as c
  union
  select '' as a, '2' as b, '' as c
  union 
  select '' as a, '' as b, '3' as c
) d;
```