# Getting total number of Distinct Users Last month in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to get the total distinct users for last month using `SQL`

this is what i have tried so fart but it is not working:

```
select
            count(distinct case when cast(saledate as date)  = datepart(month,dateadd(MONTH,-1,saledate)) then customerid end) as Num_Dist_Users_lastmonth

        from sales
```

The solution is coming as 0 which is not the right answer. I have tried using also the below mentioned solution but did not work for me

[MySQL Query to calculate the Previous Month](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1138190/mysql-query-to-calculate-the-previous-month)

Can someone help please?

I am trying to get the total distinct users in the last month.

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.  Your code would not work in MySQL.  Also define "last month".  Sample data and desired results would help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code looks like SQL Server code.  If by "last month" you mean the "last calendar month", then use `datediff()`:

```
select count(distinct case when datediff(month, saledate, getdate) = 1 then customerid ene) as Num_Dist_Users_lastmonth
from sales;
```

However, if this is the only value you want from the query, then you should filter in the `where` clause -- much more efficient in general:

```
select count(distinct customerid)
from sales
where saledate < datefromparts(year(getdate()), month(getdate()), 1) and
      saledate >= dateadd(month, -1, datefromparts(year(getdate()), month(getdate()), 1));
```

This query is structured so it can use an index on `sales(saledate)`.